Sufficient conditions for boundedness of Fourier transform
This should be a well studied topic: I am looking for sufficient conditions on a function $u(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$ ensuring that its Fourier transform is bounded. Of course one such condition is $u\in L^1$ (or finite total variation if $u$ is a measure). But nonintegrable functions with this property do exist, e.g. $u(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ has $\widehat{u}(\xi)=c\frac{\xi}{|\xi|}e^{-|\xi|}$. Are there other examples, or classes of functions with the property?

You should specify your definition of FT, since the ordinary definition includes the condition that $f\in L^2$ (or that $f$ is a measure).

$n$-homogenous function with mean zero on the sphere are such a class no? (Basically Calderon Zygmund kernels)

@Alexander: I am using the standard extension by Schwartz to tempered distributions

@Guido: you are right, but such objects are not functions, rather homogeneous distributions, since they are not locally integrable. In dim 1 you get vp(1/x), the principal value. The example I mentioned is essentially the next best thing: think of $\frac{x}{x^2+\epsilon^2}$

Of course, distributions are ok since I can regularize them

@Pietro. Yes that was the idea, sorry for being sloppy!
